# custom block tpl with custom module

Tags: 7, blocks

I have created a block-custom.tpl.php, the following is the code inside:

```
<strong>Hello World</strong>
<p>Subject:<?php print $block->subject ?></p>
<p>Content:<?php print $block->content ?></p>
```

My custom module code:

```
        function custom_block_info() {
          $blocks['my-block-id'] = array(
            'info' => t('Block Name'),
          );
          return $blocks;
        }

        /**
         * Implementation of hook_block_view().
         */
        function custom_block_view($delta='') {
          $block = array();
          switch ($delta) {
            case 'my-block-id':
              $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
              $block['content'] = custom_contents();
              break;
          }
          return $block;
        }

        /**
         * custom html block
         * @return string
         */
        function custom_contents() {
          return '
            </p><div class="body">
              Hello World, this is a example custom Block
            </div><p>
          ';
        }
```

I placed the tpl file in /module/block/ directory

I followed the tutorial of the following web page (I know it is for Drupal 6)
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/11/11/drupal-customize-block-template-file/

Of course, the result is nothing, anything I am missing? How to override the block.tpl.php?

Comment: If you are using drupal 7, it would be called `block--custom.tpl.php` and would normally be put in a theme directory, not a core module directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your code into an custom module. [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112) should get you going. You should never change code of core. This will be lost (or at least causes tidious manual work) the next time you update drupal.

Answer (score -3):

I think you may losing a hook:

function custom_theme(){

}

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit?